# Making templates for passing model to in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using bootstrap and attempting to use the panel component for rendering lookup items. It renders perfectly fine, but this was all hand coded.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Item Number 1
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Image Carousel Goes Here</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Field</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Item Number 1
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Image Carousel Goes Here</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Field</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

A JSFiddle is [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/59HvN/)

I'm wondering how it'd be possible to do something like:

```
<div class="row">
   @(foreach Item item in items)
   {
        @RenderItemView(item);
   }
</div>
```

where I could dump all of the "div.col-md-4 ... slash div" code into another cshtml file and use it as a component and just pass the model to it?

I know that I could do this, but would prefer to make this a reusable component.

```
 <div class="row">
    @foreach(Item item in items)
    {
         // instead of using a component, setting the panel-heading off item.Number,
         // panel-body by a foreach on item.ImageUrls, etc.
    }
 </div>
```

Basically, the subcomponent will be a partial view, I think, but what is the normal way of passing a model to it and it rendering at that spot (basically, like @RenderBody works on layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a partial view which holds this content:

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemType>

<div class="row">
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
         // instead of using a component, setting the panel-heading off item.Number,
         // panel-body by a foreach on item.ImageUrls, etc.
    }
</div>
```

Save the partial view in the Views/Shared folder, so that it's available everywhere. Then to use it:

`@{Html.RenderPartial("YourPartialView", Model.Items);}`

Comment: Thanks, that seems much cleaner than the way I've been doing it.